# IBM MQ commit retention with Syncpoint

Tags: ibm-mq

here is the Commit and back out from IBM Website:
when a program gets a message from a queue within a unit of work, that message remains on the queue until the program commits the unit of work, but the message is not available to be retrieved by other programs. The message is permanently deleted from the queue when the program commits the unit of work. **If the program backs out the unit of work, IBM MQ restores the queue by making the messages available to be retrieved by other programs.**

So,if our consumer dead without rollback instruction,how does the message to be handle?

Is there any retention setting of **waiting commit time** for message with SYNCPOINT  enable in IBM MQ?

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to a non-z/OS queue manager, if the program terminates abnormally without a disconnect the message will roll back.  If if it issues a disconnect without commit, the commit will be assumed in certain situations. For more details see Usage Notes 2a-c on the IBM MQ doc page [MQDISC - Disconnect queue manager](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=calls-mqdisc-disconnect-queue-manager):